# Access localhost from machine's IP

Tags: ip, localhost

I am currently trying to run my visual studio web project on a blackberry sim.

I can access my machine's IIS page from the IP address, (so when I type in 10.x.x.x, it takes me to a page for IIS).

My question is how do I access the localhost page that visual studio is running, so the page that would normally have the home Ip address in browser.

I am guessing is is (machine IP)/(something), but I dont know what the something is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio often times runs testing server when you test your code from inside VS. When VS opens a new browser window and shows you the running application you should see something like:

*localhost:####/WebProject*

That is the location of your files on separate port (whatever is in the place of ####). However, most likely this testing server will be set to not allow remote access. What I would suggest is creating a virtual directory in iis so that you can go to 10.x.x.x/WebProject and have that point to the directory that your VS project is in.

Instructions on creating a virtual directory: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx?mfr=true